# HTTP to FTP data stream conversion?

Tags: python, http, ftp, twisted

I'm wondering if anyone can offer me any guidance on this.. hope it's being posted in the right place :|.

I want to have a web server that can initiate an download stream via http and serve it out the other side via the FTP protocol.

So a user of the program would request the file and the server would initiate an http stream from another source and pass this transfer on via FTP back to the user.

Thoughts?

Comment: Is there a particular use case for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twisted, FTP, and "streaming" large files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222293/twisted-ftp-and-streaming-large-files)

Comment: DaSourcerer - spot on this is exactly what I'm after.

Comment: Duplicate question as per: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222293/twisted-ftp-and-streaming-large-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, you could get this data stream by any protocol you desire (set up your own server using sockets, rest api and so forth), save it as a file and offer it to the customer via FTP.

This is the high-level design. What exactly are you struggling with?

(By the way, keep in mind you should prefer sFTP over FTP.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: "you should prefer sFTP" I think you mean ftps? SFTP is a subsystem of SSH and a completely different protocol.

Comment: He could use either sftp or ftps for the purpose of transfering files securely, the implemantation itself could depends on his protocol choice. If you think I got something mixed up, please correct me. Thanks. :)

Comment: Well, people tend to mix SFTP and FTPS up a lot. FTPS is related to the question while SFTP is not. But you are of course right in saying that both are a secure alternative to plain FTP as far as file transfers are concerned.